# How to convert a set of arabic numbers (order numbers) to speech in c#.net?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

To make my question clear, I don't want to use `System.Speech.Synthesis` library by Microsoft, since it does not support Arabic at all ..

and I tried looking for other TTS engines but couldn't find anything helpful ..

so I figured there should be another way without using TTS .. like playing a set of audio files corresponding with my numbers.

in short, its a call system that calls for numbers in a queue .. can any one with enough experience in this area show me a good start to go on ? or if there are good libraries out there that could be used with the .net framework that already does my thing?

Comment: Maybe you can "bypass" converting to plain fonetic text and then use the Speech lib

Comment: the thing is the speech it self, I need it to be said in Arabic .. but the lib can't produce Arabic speech ! no matter how I handle it the output is the same !

Comment: Well I don't know any lib with arabic accent. Maybe this link can help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1331c5b-65e0-4856-9f42-efb2f9b5286d/tts-for-arabic?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Raskayu thank you, i'll check that out and I hope its what I am looking for ..

Comment: if it works tell me, I'll add the answer to have this on SO since it's hard to find something about it ;)